# Sphinx is building cross-references with broken paths (singlehtml output)

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, cross-reference

I have a Sphinx project that has the following structure:

```
projectRoot
|
|__mainDoc
|  |__conf.py
|  |__index.rst
|
|__subsections
   |__subsectionA.rst
   |__subsectionB.rst
```

In my conf.py, I have set my master_doc variable to "mainDoc/index", and to build the project I run the following command at the projectRoot directory: `sphinx-build -c ./mainDoc -b singlehtml . _build`

`index.rst` contains a simple `toctree` directive that lists the two subsection files like so:

```
.. toctree::
   :numbered:
   :hidden:
   :maxdepth: 4
   :caption: Contents:

   ../subsections/subsectionA
   ../subsections/subsectionB
```

subsectionA.rst:

```
.. _anchorA:

First Title
===========

This is a sample sentence.
```

subsectionB.rst:

```
Second Title
============

Please refer to :ref:`this sentence <anchorA>`
```

So far everything is pretty straightforward, and I was able to successfully build an HTML file. However, the cross-references are broken. Specifically, if the generated HTML file is in `_build/maindoc/index.html`, the link in subsectionB.rst points to `_build/maindoc/maindoc/index.html#anchora`, which is a file that doesn't exist since there's an extra `maindoc` folder in the path.

What is causing that extra folder to be inserted in the link target, and what can I do to fix that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Move the directory `subsections` under `mainDoc`, then adjust the paths. Also do a `make clean html` to purge cached files from previous builds.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but the link to anchorA still shows the double `mainDoc` folder in its target

Comment: Please provide a link to a repository containing reproducible example.